# difference between process dumps

Tags: windbg, crash-dumps

Two questions.

1. If I start task manager I can generate dump file either by right clicking on Applications Tab or right clicking on Process tab. Is there any difference in the dump file been generated from these tabs?
2. If I have a x86 application running on a x64 machine, can I use x64 task manager to generate process dump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I don't know, but probably it's the same.
2) To dump 32-bit processes on 64 bits OS, 32-bit task manager must be used:
  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\taskmgr.exe

Check the link [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2010/09/29/capturing-memory-dumps-for-32-bit-processes-on-an-x64-machine.aspx)